# How can I clear this error message 'expected intended block' in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I have a problem with my program:(python program)

```
A = input("What is ur name?") print("Your name is %s" %A)

print("Lets make a little calculations here")

Value1 = input('Lets enter our first value: ') print("Your value is %s" %Value1)

Value2 = input('Now enter the second value: ' ) print("The value you gave was %s" %Value2)

print("Now lets add or multiply this two values together, are yoy ready?")

Sign = input("Please select add(for addition) or multi(for multiplication): ")

print("You have selected %s " %Sign)

print("Loading result values...")

if Sign == '+':

print(Value1 + Value2)

elif Sign == '*':

print(Value1 * Value2)
```

It gives me the same syntax error any time. please help me.

Comment: make sure you are using spaces or tabs only(not both). the preferred indentation method is spaces (4 space characters).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more specific about the error.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the exact errors you get from your [mcve] (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 1):

Your code after a few fixes:

```
A = input("What is ur name?")
print("Your name is " + A)

print("Lets make a little calculations here")

Value1 = int(input('Lets enter our first value: '))
print("Your value is " + str(Value1))

Value2 = int(input('Now enter the second value: '))
print("The value you gave was " + str(Value2))

print("Now lets add or multiply this two values together, are yoy ready?")

Sign = input("Please select add(for addition) or multi(for multiplication): ")

print("You have selected " + Sign)

print("Loading result values...")

if Sign == '+':
    print(Value1 + Value2)

elif Sign == '*':
    print(Value1 * Value2)
```

As I understand from your code, you are new in Python, and you used C before.
In python the input method always return a String.

Also in Python instead of use "%s" in the print you can add your output like that:

```
print("some text" + variable_name)
```

The only thing you need to check that that your variables `Value1` and `Value2` are integers. you can cast your variable to other type in this way:

```
x = 1 
# cast variable into string
y = str(x) # y is a string "1"
# cast variable into int
z = int(y) # z is a integer 1
```

Also after a if statment you need use tabs, example:

```
x = 1
if x == 1:
    # we are inside the if
    print("in if")

print("after if")
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped and now am facing the multiplication and addition issue, it just add both value like 55 instead of 25 here is the code edited

Comment: Can you show me?

Comment: You cast the two variables in the input to int like my code? Its seems that that ```Value1``` and ```Value2``` are still strings in your code.

Comment: I mean when you take the input for the variable ```Value1``` do it in this way:  ```Value1 = int(input('Lets enter our first value: ')) ```. use the ```int()``` function to cast the string from the input to integer.  Do it for ```Value2``` as well.

Comment:  Thanks, it works 

Comment: Great! i edited my answer explanatiion as well

Comment: Please what's the format, I want to answer the questions by dropping the corrected code

Comment: Format of what?

Comment: Code formatting

Comment: with : ``` your code ```

Comment: please up vote my answer at least.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected Program

```
 A = input("What is ur name?")


print("Hello %s" %A)


print("Lets make a little calculations here")



Value1 = int(input('Lets enter our first value: '))

print("Your value is %s" %Value1)

Value2 = int(input('Now enter the second value: ' ))


print("The value you gave was %s" %Value2)

print("Now lets add or multiply this two values together,\n are yoy ready?")


Sign = input("Please select addition(+) or\n multiplication(*): ")

print("You have selected %s " %Sign)

print("Loading result values...")


 if Sign == '+':

    Result = Value1 + Value2

    print("Your result = " + str(Result))

 elif Sign == '*':

    Result = Value1 * Value2

    print("Your result = " + str(Result))
```

Answer (score 0):

Python uses indentation to understand your code and distinguish blocks of codes.
So, indentation is at the beginning of a code line and must be at least one space.

It's is very important in Python (it also make your code readable)

And as you said Python will give you always an error if you skip it.

```
A = input("What is ur name?") print("Your name is %s" %A)

print("Lets make a little calculations here")

Value1 = input('Lets enter our first value: ') print("Your value is %s" %Value1)

Value2 = input('Now enter the second value: ' ) print("The value you gave was %s" %Value2)

print("Now lets add or multiply this two values together, are yoy ready?")

Sign = input("Please select add(for addition) or multi(for multiplication): ")

print("You have selected %s " %Sign)

print("Loading result values...")

if Sign == '+':

    print(Value1 + Value2)

elif Sign == '*':

    print(Value1 * Value2)`
```

One more thing may be helpful for you is that you can write comments in your code, by putting a #write whatever you want here
Comments are words that won't be readed by Python, we use them to keep a notes, or as explanation for people who will read your code in the future.
And also it dosen't matter how many space you keep between lines of codes, Python will skip empty lines